# Why is the name of the variable declared twice on the same line?

Tags: javascript

I have created the following function..

```
function test(){
    var el = el = document.body;
};
test();
```

Here what does the repeated `el` represent? is they return the same value? Can anybody explain this in short? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does jQuery enter the picture?

Comment: Well, why did you create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one leaks `el` into the global scope and is completely redundant.

Comment: Not true because of hoisting.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Still redundant though.

Comment: @pimvdb, this does pollute the global namespace when run from my Firebug console.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - `var anything` pollutes the global namespace in Firebug ;)

Comment: @Kolink, I imagine the `and` conjunction makes your statement false anyways

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like it represents an erroneous double paste action.

```
ctrl+v+v
```